# How do extract the p value from a binomial test

Tags: r, extract, p-value

I have the result of a binomial test and it looks like this:

```
data:  x and n
number of successes = 0, number of trials = 7, p-value = 0.01563
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.0000000 0.4096164
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                     0
```

All I would like to know is how to extract just the p-value in R. I tried grep and pmatch but they appear to require a table or vector.

Comment: What code did you use to generate this output?

Comment: @mtoto as recognized by @ rawr, the output was generated by `binom.test(x,n)`. The p-value can be accessed from this output using `binom.test(x,n)$p.value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to do:

```
binom.test(3,15)$p.value
```

Take a look at `str(binom.test(3,15))` to see the other results from the binomial test. 3 and 15 are chosen arbitrarily so long as second number is larger than the first.